# Powershell on Mac - Import-Module PartnerCenter fails

Tags: macos, mac, powershell

I need to use the PartnerCenter module for the PowerShell on a Mac. When i try to import the module with

```
Import-Module -Name PartnerCenter
```

PowerShell says

```
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, 

Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module -Name PartnerCenter
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], FileLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I noticed, that the PartnerCenter module is of the type "binary". Other, script-type Modules, e.g. Az, can be imported without problems.

Edit:
I ran powershell using sudo after installing the module. I also did all steps postanote suggested in its reply, with the same result as described initially

Edit2:
Still not successful here... Worked around it by using a Win-Machine, but still interested in a solution.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Removed my earlier response based on your update. When I can get a hold of a Mac, I'll try this out.